# EditText input method action not working when setting imeActionLabel

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I have an Edittext with `imeoptions` as`actiongo`. and I triggered my event when pressing soft keyboard enter button.

```
mModelId.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
           // if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

                id = mModelId.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Model id in Edittext:-"+ id);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You entered "+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Before Call Volley");
                callVolley();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine but when I add actionlabel to enter key the event is not firing.  `mModelId.setImeActionLabel("Search Model", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);`. What may be the problem?

Comment: This seems to be a bug actually. It happened with me too when I set a label to the GO button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

declare edittext and OnEditorActionListener() like this

```
mModelId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
mModelId.setImeActionLabel("Search Model", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
mModelId.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
         boolean handled = false;

         if (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

              id = mModelId.getText().toString();
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You entered "+id,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              callVolley();
              handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
});
```

and you use [imeoptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionId) as actionGo then revome it, i think it override [ImeActionLabel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionLabel) 
once try this and reply

Comment: yeah working, can you brief what was the real issue?

Comment: if we use imeoptions and ImeActionLabel both then edittext prefer imeoptions over ImeActionLabel, so u are not fire event.

Answer (score 3):

`setImeActionLabel` take two parameters and the second int parameter should be one of the those that are in the `EditorInfo` class. Such as:

```
    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO
    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
    ....
```

You cannot send there any other integer like `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`

And you have to set both`imeOptions` parameter and `singleLine` parameter in XML in order it to work. Example:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Here is the code that I used and it is working:

XML Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the basic `Activity` code:

```
    mEditText2.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You entered " + v.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    mEditText2.setImeActionLabel("Search Model", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

Comment: No it wont work.... Actually editor action  works if ImeActionLabel is not set!!!

Comment: I want to know what is the problem that causes editoraction not firing when we setImeActionlabel. CAN ANYONE HERE PLEASE EXPLAIN THAT?

Comment: I really don't know but I would like to investigate it when I have time later

Comment: I have changed my answer. I have updated it with real code and it is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Supply a value for EditorInfo.actionId used when an input method is connected to the text view.

   numberEditor.mInputContentType.onEditorActionListener.onEditorAction(
                                       this, EditorInfo.IME_NULL, event))
2. Supply a value for EditorInfo.actionLabel used when an input method is connected to the text view.

Must be a string value, using '\;' to escape characters such as '\n' or '\uxxxx' for a unicode character.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked at Android 2.1 and Android 4.0 versions and your code is working fine. `IME_ACTION_GO` event is reported in case EditText has `singleLine` option specified to `true`. In case it is specified to `false` `actionId` has `IME_NULL` value independently of the `setImeActionLabel` was called or no.

In the TextView.onKeyDown method i've found that `IME_NULL` actionId is used when `KEYCODE_ENTER` is detected

```
mEditor.mInputContentType.onEditorActionListener.onEditorAction(
                                this, EditorInfo.IME_NULL, event))
```

Perhaps it is custom keyboard issue. Do you use any? If so try these changes:

instead of

```
mModelId.setImeActionLabel("Search Model", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

should be

```
mModelId.setImeActionLabel("Search Model", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

Comment: I had tested in 4.4, No custom keyboards are used. My code runs when Imeactionlabel is not used. I would replace KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER with EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO and let you know if it works