# How to display "search" as text instead of Serach icon on android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

How to replace the search icon with text "Search" on soft keyboard.

```
<EditText 
android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />
```

Comment: at least on some OS versions, **imeOptions** only work when **inputType** is set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using imeOptions use the following :-

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
         android:inputType="text"/>
```

For handling click listener do as follows :

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() { 
@Override 
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
        performSearch(); 
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
} });
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753910/behaviour-of-imeoptions-imeactionid-and-imeactionlabel) stackoverflow question.

Try to set

- `android:imeActionLabel` in XML or
- in java code with `.setImeActionLabel()`

`editText.setImeActionLabel(getString(R.string.xxx), EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);`

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299861/edittext-input-method-action-not-working-when-setting-imeactionlabel) for a possible solution.