# EditText setImeActionLabel not working in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am facing issue with `editText.setImeActionLabel` option. It's working fine on premarshmallow devices but **not working on marshmallow**.

Here is my code for reference,

```
edt_testIMEIoptions.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    edt_testIMEIoptions.setImeActionLabel("Login", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

    edt_testIMEIoptions.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Done called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also Tried with blow options,

```
EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO 
EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
```

Please guide me one the same.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538331/android-cant-figure-how-to-use-setimeactionlabel) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299861/edittext-input-method-action-not-working-when-setting-imeactionlabel) answer.

Comment: Above solution not working, Done icon gets replace with search icon but text not appearing on it.

Answer (score 4):

After lot of trial and error finally below solution work for me.
set below field in XMl,

```
android:singleLine="true"
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Code in main class,

```
etPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            /*
            after entering the password, When user clicks on done button,
            keyboard gets hide and clear the focus from the password edittext
             */

            if (event != null && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            } else if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || event == null
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                etPassword.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
                // Your code                    
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help others.